# Cursor not found

Tags: postgresql

i have created procedure, inside used cursor to update the some data, while calling the procedure it's getting the error.

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE bal_upd(p_id int) as 
$$
    DECLARE rc record;
    ----- cursor
            bal_upd1 CURSOR (p_id int)
            for 
               select * from tbal where custid = p_id;

    begin
               open bal_upd1 (p_id);

              loop
                  FETCH bal_upd1 into rc;
                  exit when not found;
                  update  t_trans set balance = balance + rc.trans;
                  COMMIT;
             end loop;
            close bal_upd1;

    end;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call bal_upd(1)
```

ERROR:  cursor "bal_upd1" does not exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function bal_upd(integer) line 12 at FETCH
SQL state: 34000

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE bal_upd(p_id int) as 
$$
    DECLARE rc record;
    ----- cursor
            bal_upd1 CURSOR (p_id int)
            for 
               select * from tbal where custid = p_id;

    begin
               open bal_upd1 (p_id);

              loop
                  FETCH bal_upd1 into rc;
                  exit when not found;
                  update  t_trans set balance = balance + rc.trans;
                  COMMIT;
             end loop;
            close bal_upd1;

    end;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call bal_upd(1)
```

ERROR:  cursor "bal_upd1" does not exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function bal_upd(integer) line 12 at FETCH
SQL state: 34000

Comment: You never declared the cursor.

Comment: Why do you want to use a cursor? Personally I never used them in the last 15 years of database programming, they never had any added value. Treat your data as a set and you never need a cursor.

Comment: did you get the your question, please let me know where the problem in above code. i wanted to update the database records one by one how we can do that? with cursor

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function or a loop for that:

```
UPDATE t_trans
SET balance = t_trans.balance + t.trans
FROM (SELECT sum(trans) AS trans
      FROM tbal
      GROUP BY custid) AS t
WHERE t_trans.custid = t.custid;
```

Comment: will this work with multiple records? i mean tbal has daily transactions with same custid. i don't this update statement will work  until you loop them update it one by one

Comment: Then you should aggregate, as in my fixed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, failed. I just found just use for loop (implicit cursor) is far more simple.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE temp TABLE tbal (
    custid bigint
    , trans numeric
);
INSERT INTO tbal VALUES (1 , 1);
INSERT INTO tbal VALUES (1 , 2);
CREATE temp TABLE t_trans (
    custid bigint
    , balance numeric
);
INSERT INTO t_trans VALUES (1 , 10);
COMMIT;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bal_upd (bigint)
    AS $func$
DECLARE
    rc record;
BEGIN
    FOR rc IN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        tbal
    WHERE
        custid = $1 LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'custid: %, trans: % ' , rc.custid , rc.trans;
            UPDATE
                t_trans ta
            SET
                balance = balance + (rc.trans)
            WHERE
                ta.custid = (rc.custid);
        END LOOP;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then call it. `CALL bal_upd(1);`